# Large linked .xlsb workbooks

Tags: excel, hyperlink

It now seems necessary to take my 50MB workbook and split it into 3 separate workbooks.  Ultimately, when this program is moved to different computers, these 3 files will need to be moved together in order to function (of course).  Is there a way for all of the links and conditional formatting to remain absolute?  That is, all the files will be in the same folder, so a path would not be needed or wanted, just the workbook name and the sheet/cell reference.
If this is not possible or practical, am I missing something?  Is there another way to do what I want to do, which is allow a very large spreadsheet to run on less powerful machines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the files are in the same relative locations, the links should update automatically. As far as I know, for the files in the same folder, it's not an issue at all. The same with going down the folder path. Problems might start when going the other way, so I'd keep them in the same folder.

Conditional formatting might be an issue though, but you could try linking just the conditions to the workbook you're trying to format.

To speed up the spreadsheet you can try manual calculations. I don't know how your spreadsheet looks like or how slow are the machines you're talking about, but that helps in most cases

P.S. Sorry for an answer when it should really be a comment, but I don't have enough reputation yet to do so